# Alternate or optional Tag in XSD

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I have xsd for validation structure of XML which could appear with two types of same tag. so i have to handle these both scenerio in my xsd. I searched and found alternate and choice tag are there to acomplish my requirment but could not able to insert in proper formate:

following are the type of tag:

**Either**

```
<funcs>
<joint>
<functionName value=""/>
<indataType value=""/>
</joint>
</funcs>
```

**OR**

```
<funcs path="myinfo.txt"/>
```

when i insert alternate tag found following exception:

```
Exception: s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'funcs' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: alternative.
```

Comment: Can you post your XSD ?

Answer (score 0):

My answer wold help you if it's possible to name the 'funcs' tag differently in your cases.

You could use this XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element ref="funcs_1"/>
                <xsd:element name="funcs_2" type="f2"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="funcs_1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="joint" type="f1" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="f1">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="functionName" type="f3">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="indataType" type="f3">
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="f3">
        <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="f2">
        <xsd:attribute name="path" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

To validate these two XML,

XML1:

```
<root>
    <funcs_1>
        <joint>
            <functionName value=""/>
            <indataType value=""/>
        </joint>
    </funcs_1>
</root>
```

XML2:

```
<root>
    <funcs_2 path="myinfo.txt"/>
</root>
```